# Zend Cache Exception: 'cache_dir "/home/(...)/application/../data/tmp/" is not writable'

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm **really** new to Zend, few days of use.

I'm getting a fatal error message:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'cache_dir "/home/[REDACTED]/application/../data/tmp/" is not writable' in /home/[REDACTED]/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
Stack trace:
#0 /home/[REDACTED]/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(181): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/hom...')
#1 /home/[REDACTED]/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(129): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/home/user/Proj...')
#2 /home/[REDACTED]/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 /home/[REDACTED]/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, false, false)
#4 /home/[REDACTED]/application/Bootstrap.php(42): Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', Array, Array)
#5 /home/[REDACTED]/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(669): Bootstrap->_initCache()
#6 /home/[REDACTED]/library/Zend/Applica in /home/[REDACTED]/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209
```

According to the error message, I would expect a folder permissions issue on the `tmp` directory. The directory is, however, writable:

```
user@[REDATCED]:~/[REDATCED]/data$ ls -hal
total 24K
drwxrwxr-x  6 user user 4,0K Jan  7 18:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 user user 4,0K Jan  9 12:50 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4,0K Dez 17 11:42 locales
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4,0K Dez 17 11:42 logs
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4,0K Dez 17 11:42 sessions
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4,0K Jan  7 18:40 tmp
```

The workaround is to comment the following lines on `application/Bootstrap.php`:

```
    protected function _initCache() {
          $frontendOptions = array(
              'lifetime' => 7200, // cache lifetime of 2 hours
              'automatic_serialization' => true
          );

          $backendOptions = array(
              'cache_dir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../data/tmp/' // Directory where
          );

          // getting a Zend_Cache_Core object
          $this->cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File',
            $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);

          Zend_Registry::set('cache', $this->cache);

          Zend_Date::setOptions(array(
              'cache' => $this->cache
          ));
```

This workaround was suggested by a coworker, I have no idea what I'm doing here or even if this code is part of Zend or our codebase. I don't like ugly hacks, or "fixing" stuff by commenting out code, or doing anything without knowing what I'm doing, or the reason behind it.

Besides, the code seems to be working on my coworkers' machines. And every time I pull their code commits from the repository I get an uncommented copy anyway.

I probably could exclude the file from the repository or anything like that (I'm new to git as well), but I really prefer:

- Knowing the cause for the error
- Knowing the solution

Comment: The error message clearly states that some directory (or file) _is not writable_ which usually points to permission issues.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, that is correct and it was indeed the case.

Comment: FYI, by commenting out the method in your last code example you were disabling initialisation of the cache object in your application (which is what was throwing the permissions error). It's likely this would have caused problems elsewhere in your application (which would error when it tried to use the now non-existent cache resource).

Comment: @TimFountain Thanks for taking your time to explain this, as I said I'm really **very** new to Zend and haven't got much clue as how things work (to be honest someone just installed Zend and NetBeans on my machine and said "here, use it").

Answer (score 5):

This error typically occurs because of permissions.

To solve this, if you're using apache as your web server, assign ownership to apache.

On my Fedora Core machine I solved this by simply issuing:

```
chown my_current_name:apache -R /var/www/project_name
```

Comment: This is the most adequate way to solve this issue, for linux users. Worked on my Fedora 20, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing this question I noticed my mistake, the `tmp` directory is writable by myself and other users of the same group, apparently Zend will access the files as another user. The solution was to `chmod 777` on the folder, making it writable.

Comment: or maybe is it apache acessing the files as the apache user?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, solved it by following a simple step.
lib>Zend>Cache>Backend>File.php
find this line

```
protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => 'null',
```

Remove the quote and leave it as

```
protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => null,
```

It really worked for me.